# UIToolBarButton Image and Text

Tags: ios, ios7, uitoolbar

I cant create a Bar Button Item with an image after specifying "Title" and "Image Name" . Is it normal? How can i do it ? I am looking to create a button as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can set a button with either with image or title. So, you can add button image (title on image).

Comment: Do it programmatically. That's the best way to add title to your image - so much flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide your own button (could be a UIButton with title and image) and create your button with `initWithCustomView:`.

You can do this in IB by dragging a UIButton into the UIBarButtonItem (and then configure the UIButton instead of the UIBarButtonItem), or you can do it in code.